# clipdrawable setlevel per width on imageview

Tags: android, image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_ellipse"
    android:gravity="top" />
```

My `imageview` takes that as source, what that does when I call `setLevel(5000)` it draws half the image from top, from 0 to 10000. However I want him to draw half the image based on width. like I want him to draw 50 % of image. not from top but from right.

Comment: Question is quite unclear.

Comment: solved it by changing vertical to horizontal. and gravity to left.